# Failed to build gem native extension on macOS

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems

I want to run this workflow called TarSynFlow (https://github.com/seoanezonjic/TarSynFlow). It has some requirements that I am trying to install, but am hitting some issues, specifically with installing scbi_distributed_blast. The TarSynFlow github page and original source (https://github.com/dariogf/scbi_distributed_blast) for this say to type:

```
gem install scbi_distributed_blast
```

Tried this but get the following:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing scbi_distributed_blast:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/Users/ginamchaput/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby -I
/Users/ginamchaput/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210830-52462-idkyvy.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lcrypto... yes
checking for -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... yes
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW in time.h... yes
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
CXXFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result -Wno-address
creating Makefile
current directory: /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:
./project.h:119:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/3.0.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out
```

I did see other posts suggest using `sudo gem install scbi_distributed_blast` ; I did try it but same error.

I'm using macOS Big Sur; XCode v 12.5.1; ruby (installed via RVM) v 3.0.0p0; If anyone has advice to get this installed that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

From this:

```
./project.h:119:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
```

looks like you need ssl dev libraries to compile the gem. If you have xcode installed, try with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Another way to install the required libs is to use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with:

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
```

---

**Update**

If you have all the required libraries installed, then try installing `eventmachine` by itself, but specifying the path where the ssl libraries are located.

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

then, try installing `scbi_distributed_blast` again.

Comment: `eventmachine` is a dependency of [`scbi_mapreduce`](https://github.com/dariogf/scbi_map_reduce/blob/master/scbi_mapreduce.gemspec) which is a dependency of `scbi_distributed_blast`

Comment: So I tried both brew install openssl as well as the xcode-select options; both say that they are installed and up to date. Reinstalled via homebrew but no luck. Do I need to have a PATH somewhere or something when I try running gem install?

Comment: @Gina I've updated my answer. Try again and tell me if that works